# Object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, email, encoder

I'm trying to attach an xlsx file to my email. I looked up solutions and it involves using email.encoders. But when I use this solution I get an error. I'm using a solution that someone else has working.

```
File "C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\AppTera\dev\MTC_test\MTC_sender.py", line 41, in sendmail
    s.sendmail(FROMADDR, TOADDR, message.as_string())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

```
def sendmail():
      SERVER = 'server.com'
      FROMADDR = "joe@example.com"
      TOADDR = ['bob@example.com']
      CCADDR = ['bill@example.com']

      message = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
      message['From'] = FROMADDR
      message['To'] = TOADDR
      message['Subject'] = "Reporting for IVR Application"

      BODY = "Hello Angela,\n\nI'm attaching the reports for %s/%s. These   are the same reports\
 you have requested in the past.\n\nPlease let me know if you need any additional reports.\n\n\
 Thank you"% (str(MONTH), str(YEAR))
      message.attach(MIMEText(BODY, 'plain'))

      filename = "results.csv.xlsx"
      path = r'C:\Documents and  Settings\Desktop\MonthlyReports\MTC\%s_%s' % (str(YEAR), str(MONTH))
      os.chdir(path)
      fileMsg = MIMEBase('application', 'xlsx')
      fileMsg.set_payload(open('results.csv.xlsx', 'rb').read())
      encoders.encode_base64(fileMsg)
      fileMsg.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename=results.csv.xls')
      message.attach(fileMsg)


      s = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER, 25)
      s.set_debuglevel(1)
      s.sendmail(FROMADDR, TOADDR, message.as_string())
      s.quit()
```

Is there another way that I can send an attached file along with a body message?

Comment: I played around with your code a bit, and it works if `TOADDR` is a plain string instead of a list.  The docs say it can be a list, so I don't know why this happens.

Comment: Thanks that did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s` is a SMTP object which you created by `s = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER, 25)`. So the parameters for `s.sendmail(FROMADDR, TOADDR, message.as_string())` should be according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail).

> **SMTP.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, msg[, mail_options, rcpt_options])**
>
> Send mail. The required arguments are an **RFC 822** from-address string, a list of **RFC 822** to-address strings (a bare string will be treated as a list with 1 address), and a message string. The caller may pass a list of ESMTP options (such as 8bitmime) to be used in MAIL FROM commands as mail_options. ESMTP options (such as DSN commands) that should be used with all RCPT commands can be passed as rcpt_options. (If you need to use different ESMTP options to different recipients you have to use the low-level methods such as mail(), rcpt() and data() to send the message.)

Make sure FROMADDR is a string(not a list), TOADDR should be a string or a list of strings(which are *RFC 822* email format strings).

Comment: The problem lies within the attachment part of the sendmail. You can see that both TOADDR and FROMADDR are a single string.

Comment: Try to print `message` and `message.as_string()` after you assign the `['From'], ['To'], and ['Subject']` part.

Comment: For multiple recipients use `msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)`

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but I was tearing my hair out about it, hopefully someone doing the same will find this.

When you are using a MIME Multipart container it is different than sending it with standard smtplib.

You can define a list of recipients as such:

```
RECIPIENTS = ['abc@abc.com', 'xyz@xyz.com']
```

Then the message['To'] should be formatted this way:

```
msg['To'] = ', '.join(RECIPIENTS)
```

And finally the code block for the destinations is back to a list not a string

```
#Provide the contents of the email.
    response = client.send_raw_email(
        Source=msg['From'],
        Destinations=['abc@abc.com', 'xyz@xyz.com'],
        RawMessage={
            'Data':msg.as_string(),
        },
#        ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET
    )
```

This is probably not the cleanest answer, but hopefully it helps someone out.